# Hard regex with sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

In a script.sh file, I have the following line:

```
ExecStart=ssh -nN -R 46:192.168.0.1:56 192.168.0.2
```

I try to replace with sed the second port (56 here) knowing that its value can vary between 1 and 65535.

So I tried that without success :

```
sed -i -e "s/:.*[[:space/]]/other port number/2g' script.sh
```

Could you help me solve my regex?

Comment: does `sed 's/:[0-9]*/other port number/2'` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use:

```
sed -i "s/:[0-9]\{1,5\} /:other port number /" script.sh
```

---

```
$ other_port_number="123"
$ echo "ExecStart=ssh -nN -R 46:192.168.0.1:56 192.168.0.2" | sed "s/:[0-9]\{1,5\} /:$other_port_number /"
ExecStart=ssh -nN -R 46:192.168.0.1:123 192.168.0.2
```